# Best practice for renaming property/method names that are reserved words?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, naming-conventions

I'm creating a class. What's the best practice for naming properties/methods when your preferred name is a reserved word?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I usually try to think of some synonymous alternative word, or variation, though it doesn't sound like that is applicable for you.

Alternatively, you can use the '@' prefix (in C#) or [square braces] (in VB.NET) to explicitly avoid the conflict with reserved words in the language.

Comment: These methods work exactly as advertised.  It's still best to try to avoid using verbatim reserved words, however, if your assembly is going to be re-used elsewhere.  If it's an entirely self-contained project, go for it.

Answer (score 2):

In VB.NET, you can enclose the property name within square brackets:

```
Public Property [Make] As String
```

(I'm not sure about C#, but you also tagged the post as vb.net)

Answer (score 1):

Neither make nor model are reserved C# words.  In the case that you do need to use a reserved word, the best thing to do is to try to come up with a synonym.

Comment: Visual Studio has intellisense for both make and model as though they're reserved words. Actually, it appears they're part of the BCL. Is that correct?